# jQuery and CSS animation - bug when calling setTimeout to repeat the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an animation, which can be seen here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/st.anthony/#administration_page

The principal and vice principal's message fade in and fade out alternatively and on completion, I call setTimeout to loop over the animation after every 16 seconds.

The animation works fine for the first time I call it. The second time, only the principal's message fades in, and then there is nothing on the screen for about 8 seconds. After this, the animation has another normal iteration and the bug occurs again. I have tried to debug it using developer tools, and I notice the class is not getting applied, every time the screen is blank. Apart from that there are no error.

Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="images/the_principal.jpg" alt="school principal" class="admin-pic">
            <img src="images/mrs_cooke_optimised.png" alt="school vice principal" class="admin-pic">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p class="text" id="principal">
                "Education is a simple yet a serious process. It is a process of making a human being into 'being human'.
                Stress at our institution is on this aspect.<br>I invite you to join us and make our country proud."
                <br><br>-The Principal
            </p>
            <p class="text" id="vice-principal">
                "We are all Indians firstly and lastly.Whatever anyone else might say, we need to uphold this God-given identity
                through our actions, thoughts and what we might say.<br>
                Long live the Indian Republic."
                <br><br> -The Vice Principal
            </p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.admin-pic {
    display: block;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity:0;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin:0;
    top :20%;
    left : 50%;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 40%;
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond',serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align-last: center;
    opacity: 0;

}

.fadeInDownExit{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear backwards;
    -o-animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear backwards;
    animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear backwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInDownExit {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    10%, 90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40%);
        -o-transform: translateY(40%);
        transform: translateY(40%);
    }

}
.fadeInUpExit{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInUpExit 8s linear backwards;
    -o-animation: fadeInUpExit 8s linear backwards;
    animation: fadeInUpExit 8s linear backwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInUpExit {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
        -o-transform: translateY(100%);
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    10%, 90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
function display(){
                $('.text').each(function () {
                    var delay = $(this).index();
                    $(this).css('animation-delay', delay*8 + 's');
                    $(this).addClass('fadeInUpExit').one(animationEnd, function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('fadeInUpExit');
                        $(this).css('animation-delay',0+'s');
                    });

                });

                $('.admin-pic').each(function () {
                    var delay = $(this).index();
                    $(this).css('animation-delay', delay*8 + 's');
                    $(this).addClass('fadeInDownExit').one(animationEnd, function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('fadeInDownExit');
                        $(this).css('animation-delay',0+'s');
                    });

                });
                setTimeout(display,16000);

            }
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

display();
```

Comment: Typo in event name. Should be `animationend`. [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c3dn10y6/)

Comment: @charlietfl - animationEnd is a defined variable. I have added it to my code now. Also your fiddle is having the same problem as mine, every even iteration, doesn't show up the vice principal animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you call the `display()` repetition too early with the `settimeout` and because of this the animation finishes after you have relaunched the display and cause this bug.

As an example, if you set a longer timeout, the problem doesn't happen.

Try changing your code to this to see it working correctly :

```
setTimeout(display,16100);
```

**UPDATE**

As this change point out the problem, I would not recommand to use it as a solution.
The best way would be to use the animation events only, because this is the only way to be sure that the code is repeteated after the animation has finished.

A working example with the first part of your code would be :

```
var $txt = $('.text');
var incr = 0;

function display() {
  var $this = $txt.eq(incr);
  $this.one('animationend', function() {
    incr = incr ? 0 : 1;
    $this.removeClass('fadeInUpExit');
      display();
  });
  $this.addClass('fadeInUpExit');
}

display();
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :) This had me going for days!

Comment: glad that it helped. But I wouldn't recommand to use it as a solution because the problem can still be present after a few loops... See my update for a better solution